# Making a variable that controls number of columns or rows

Tags: excel

In Office 365 Excel
I'm trying to create a number of rows from a defined variable, that increase by 1.

eg:
i = 9

I then want 9 rows which each increase by 1.
so row1 = 1,
row2 = 2,
and so forth

I would like to control both "i" and the increase number.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Do you actually mean : "I then want 9 cells in a column which each increase by 1.." ?